# Custom columns in Wordpress database

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress

I have two websites (one Wordpress and one PHP) with two separate databases. I would like to make a custom column in the Wordpress users table, with an identifier from the PHP database table. This way i have a link between the two databases.

Is it possible to create custom columns in the Wordpress database without breaking the website and if it's possible, how do you make it? Can you make a new column in phpmyadmin directly without problems or maybe a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly add a new column to the wp_users using PHPMyAdmin - or script it from PHP. There might be a plugin that let's you change columns too, but I've never looked as PHPMyAdmin or similar direct access are better options.

However, I don't think you should do this.

The point about WordPress is its consistency. Changing the column structure will have no effect on the core code now, but you never know when that table might get updated in the core.

An alternative would be to add a meta key in wp_usermeta. IF you really want a table, then the safest option is to create a custom table (eg wp_user_connections), and put your linking in there. With either, you could then JOIN whatever data you wanted.

Comment: The idea is that i want to be able to update "user_login" and "user_pass" in the wordpress user database, when i update the user on my PHP site (this site is an admin site with info about the users). I need an ID that match between the two databases so that i can insert, update or delete a user in the Wordpress database, when i do it on my admin site. im not sure how to do it via another table or wp_usermeta. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You'd add a row to wp_usermeta with the external ID. In PHP like this:

`update_usermeta( $user_id, '_external_id', $user_external_id );`

Then, your update SQL would be something like:

`UPDATE wp_users u
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta um ON um.user_id = u. ID AND um.meta_key = '_external_id'
SET u.user_login = [YOUR_EXTERNAL_LOGIN]
WHERE um.meta_value = [YOUR EXTERNAL_ID]`

Having said that, if you want to login users to  WordPress based on an external system, there are easier ways than by syncing the two sets of databases.